# Write source XML in an XSLT for development purposes

Tags: xslt

I have to write an XSLT without knowing the input XML. So I want to start by writing an XSLT that will simply return the input XML without any transformation. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/07/copy-xml-as-is-with-xslt.html

Comment: The solution is unnecessarily complex for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is known as the [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). To be general, you need to ensure that all attribute and non-attribute nodes are copied, recursively:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the identity transform does not guarantee that the output is identical on the surface level (i.e. some hash calculation might yield a different result, for instance). E.g. attributes could be reordered - this has no impact on the [infoset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infoset) or validity.